# Will a timer keep running indefinetly until its .cancel method has been invoked

Tags: java

Below code starts and runs two timers in order, I would have thought that the first timer would stop running once the second timer is initialised. It seems that when a Timer is given a new reference its previous reference just keeps executing the given task ?

```
public class TimerTest {

    private TimerTask timerTask;
    private Timer timer;
    private int counter = 0;
    private final int delay = 1000;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new TimerTest().runTimer();
        new TimerTest().runTimer();
    }

    private void runTimer(){
        timer = new Timer();
        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {          
                ++counter;
                System.out.println("output - "+counter);
            }
        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, delay, delay);
    }

}
```

Comment: There are no references to the first timer any more. It will stop when the garbage collector works on it

Comment: @Armen: Even if the Timer is not referenced anymore, the task it has scheduled is still referenced by the background running thread of the timer. It won't stop.

Comment: @Armen no first timer is not used by the developer but it still in the memory and is in running mode until it cann't the application or cancel the timer explictly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Assigning an object reference to a variable doesn't modify the state of the object. The object is, BTW, unable to know if it's assigned to 0, 1 or several variables.

Moreover, note that the second timer is assigned to a different variable than the first one, since you instantiate two TimerTest objects, each having their own timer field.